# Quest 'Get Junior': Where do I find the documents?

Tags: the-witcher-3

One point of the todo-list is
*Read all documents you've found*
(I play the german version, not sure if this is the same in english). I have read every book, every paper in my inventory, but can't solve this point.

If I really have found this documents already, which paper should I read exactly?
Where should I search for this documents if I have to get them first?

Comment: What part of the quest are you on? Is it the very beginning?

Comment: This entry appears on the quest list between 'Visit the arena of Junior' (solved) and 'Speak with Dijkstra about the connection to the Redanians' (top of the list, unsolved)

Answer (score 3):

Go to your quests and do the find the secret stash using witcher sense. When you get to the spot use witcher sense and turn the torch to open the wall. You can then loot the place to get a letter and that will complete that part of the quest.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the arena where you beat up minor men with the dwarves. It's all the way back around the arena next to the chair.