# Quest 'Get Junior': No other way to open the wall to a secret stash?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Geralt needs to open a wall near the arena . I think he should say something about the scratches on the floor in front of the wall (appears red, but no 
magnifying glass visible).
 It seems that only then the torch to the right (also appears in red, but no magnifying glass visible) gets usable.

Maybe this is connected to my problem in [Quest 'Get Junior': Where do I find the documents?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224478/quest-get-junior-where-do-i-find-the-documents)

Do you know any other way to open this 'door'?

BTW:
I have a 'Message from Igor' in my quest inventory. Unfortunately, reading this message doesn't help or activate anything for me.

Comment: You can try using aard on the wall.

Comment: @Bob: Aard doesn't work for me, but thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 7):

I found that the activation point for the torch on the right was tiny, and hard to hit naturally.

I would suggest angling your camera as far up as possible, and "scanning" the torch area. You should find an usable area, which will open the door.

> For a criminal enterprise / betting arena, I found the amount of cash on hand to be very disappointing. ;)